# Conversion of string representation of a set into a set

Tags: string, python-2.7, set, representation

Given (in Python 2.7)..

```
myString='{hello,world}'
```

How do I go about converting the above into the `set object {'hello', 'world'}` ?

I tried `eval(myString)`, but it throws `NameError: name 'hello' is not defined`

I tried `ast.literal_eval(myString)` but it throws `ValueError: malformed string`

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you were close. If you put quotes around the individual elements, you can use Python's `eval`

```
>>> myString = "{'hello','world'}"
>>> eval(myString)
{'world', 'hello'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you can do it this way:

1. First, if myString always starts with "{" and ends with "}", you get rid of those first by substring.

   String myString = "{hello,world}";
   String myStringFixed = myString.substring(1, myString.length() - 1);

The output of myStringFixed now would be "hello,world"

2. Convert the string into an array throught splitting.

   String[] arrayOfStrings = myStringFixed.split(",");

The output of arrayOfStrings would be ["hello", "world"];

3. Now you can create a set via that array by running a loop and add those elements to the set.

   Set stringSet = new HashSet();

   for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++)
   {
       stringSet.add(arrayOfStrings[i]);
   }

Comment: ah sorry for not mentioning earlier, but i'm actually coding in python. i get what you're doing though - list slicing to pull out the important bits and putting them back together, i'll work out something similar in python!